# What is happening between last resource load and page render?

Tags: html, render

I am trying to optimize my website and decrease page load times. I am starting to implement optimizations to the critical rendering path, but I'm not sure what is causing a ~150ms lag between the time the last item finishes loading, and when the DOMContentLoaded/load events are fired and the page renders. From the screenshot below, you can see there is gap between the final item loading from cache at ~550ms, and the DOMContentLoaded/load events firing simultaneously just after 700ms.

[image]

What is happening in this 150ms window?

The last 2 items on the list are images that are pre-loaded inside a `$(document).ready(...)` jQuery function. If this pre-loading finishes before the 150ms gap, doesn't this mean that the gap cannot be attributed to waiting for javascript execution?